# jQuery - few values in selector function

Tags: php, jquery

I have simple selector function inside php script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // create a new date and insert it
    var myDate = new Date(<?php echo $date; ?>)
    $.countdown('#<?php echo $ei_id; ?>', myDate);
});
</script>
```

This script transfer a value of 'myDate' into next js script

```
jQuery.countdown = function(selector, dateValue) {
    var dateV = dateValue;
};
```

But I must transfer another one variable f.ex. `$time` from first to second script.
I try to make it via simple js table (compare variables `$time` and `$date` into one via this simple table) but the php script is working with `while() {}` and in this situation in second script I have always only the last value of `$time` from `while()` loop.

Probably it must be done in jquery style but I don't know how.

---

A php file

```
while (){

$time = '10,10';
$ei_id = abc;
$date = '2012,03,10';

?>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // create a new date and insert it
        var myDate = new Date(<?php echo $date; ?>)
        $.countdown('#<?php echo $ei_id; ?>', myDate);
    });
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js_external.js"></script>

<?php
}
```

// of course, values of $time, $date, $ei_id are generated from dBase - into external js file always must be sending this three variables. At this moment I have two variables, must add thid third.

a js_external.js file

```
jQuery.countdown = function(selector, dateValue) {
    var dateV = dateValue;

    // here I must have a value of $time from php file

};
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your problem is and I'm not sure if this is a good question for SO at all.

Comment: the question is simple, as I think - how transfer a value of php variable $time from php script into second jquery script via first jqery function $(document).ready(function() {. How to write it simpler?

Comment: please, show some code that make sense with your context... the code you shown is far from your situation..

Comment: @Felix  - do not try to pick holes in the whole, I'm not sure if you really wants to think about problem

Answer (score 0):

as Hannibal said - sometimes the answer is as simple as the question -> var xyz = [a,b];
I donn't know is it a better solution, but it works.